# Finding prime numbers and then putting the prime numbers into an output file

Tags: c++, function, file-io, output, primes

So I have an assignment for class in which I have to ask the user for an integer in between 1 and 3000. Then my program should be able to tell if the integer is a prime number or not. Lastly, I would have to put that integer into a file, but only if it is a prime number. But my issue is my syntax, I am not sure if it's right(well actually obviously it's not because I keep getting errors). Is it possible to open a file in a function? and if so does it become a parameter?
I have been going through my textbook and googling as much as possible for some guidance but I'm still feeling lost. Any advice would help.

Edit: My logic as far as the numbers work, however when I add the code to write to a file, I'm now getting errors.

The two errors are

C2440 initializing: cannot convert from constant char to int (line 18)

C2079 myfile: uses undefined class'std::basic_fstream <>char,std::char_traits>'

Here's my code so far!

```
    // Project 5.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //


#include <fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//functions

void prime(int x);

//variables
int x=0;
int i;
char answer;
fstream myfile("castor_primes.txt");

int main()

{


    do
    {
        cout << "Enter an integer between 1 and 3000 \n";
        cin >> x;
        if (x == 1)
        {
            cout << x << " is not a prime number.\n";
        }
       else if (x < 1 || x>3000)
        {
            cout << x << " is an invalid number. \n";
        }
        else
        {

            prime(x);
        }

        cout << "Do you want to enter another number? Y/N \n";
        cin >> answer;
    } while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');

    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}

void prime(int x)
{


    if (x == 2)
    {
        cout << "Yes, " << x << " is Prime\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 2; i < x; i++)
        {
            if (x%i == 0)
            {
                cout << x << " is not a prime number\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        if (x == i)
        {
            cout << "Yes, " << x << " is Prime\n";
            myfile << x ;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a little note: Every prime number is odd except for 2. This shouts for some optimization...

Comment: "well actually obviously it's not because I keep getting errors" - well... how about posting those errors? I ran your code on Code::Blocks without the `#include "stdafx.h"` and it worked fine. @Garmekain, about the optimisation - there are actually more ways to optimise it, but that's not related to the question. I would highly encourage you to test if a file opening process has succeded by using the `outputFile.good()` method. It returns true if the opening was successful. After you post your errors, I will proceed to answer the question and provide some advices for similar, future projects

Comment: @Fureeish That's why it's just a little note.

Comment: FYI, if you convert the answer to lower case or upper case, you only have to make one compare.  See `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`.

Comment: Works for me in GCC without `stdafx.h` header if the behaviour is to enter a number and if it is prime write it in the first position of the `castor_primes.txt` file(and create it if it doesn't exist). As @Fureeish pointed out, you should post the errors you are getting.

Comment: You should search the internet for "c++ prime number testing" as there are some checks you can do to reduce the execution time.

Comment: I made an edit to my program but now I am having writing into the output file issues>>I also added info on what errors I am running into specifically above. It is on the file declaration.

Comment: Where is line 18?

Answer (score -1):

`#include "stdafx.h"` includes a pre-compiled header file when using Microsoft Visual Studio. Check to see if that file exists and if it is correct (depending on the errors you see).

There is no reason to pass the outputFile into the `prime()` function since you are opening and closing it in the function. Although it works just fine if you do.

It is a parameter of the function call (if that is your question) and is a global variable since it is defined outside the `main()` function.

As some one else suggested the code functions if the aforementioned `#include "stdafx.h"` is removed, but I am not sure how that affects the compilation in Visual Studio.

Comment: Downvoted. This is not a valid answer that gets rid of OP's errors.

Comment: Correct, however it does answer the question about opening a file in a function.